# Concurrency Access in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, concurrency

I have following code to access the database

```
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

        String hql ="Select o.id FROM Orders o ORDER BY o.id DESC";
        Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
        query.setFirstResult(0);
        query.setMaxResults(1);
```

perform some computation from the extracted data and the data produced from calculation should be unique

```
        session.save(inOrder);
        session.flush();

        session.clear();
        session.close();
```

But when I run this code when two requests come simultaneously, they get same data and ConstraintViolationException is thrown.

What is the best way to solve this problem

Comment: One way to avoid this problem is to catch that exception and handle the error messages properly. But it is better if you can handle the concurrency at the method which is producing the same results.

Comment: Will synchronize serve my purpose here as I want that read should not happen till write is pending

Comment: You can think of using `ReadWriteLock` from `java.util.concurrent.locks`. You can find lot of examples online

Comment: Doesnt hibernate support separate thread pool for each session

Comment: @Rp- Hibernate Session is **NOT** thread-safe.

Comment: That is right, Session is not thread safe. Sorry for the misconception. I deleted my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can lock object being processed using setLockMode, see [docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch05.html)